# Array: selection sort doesn't display

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What I'm supposed to do is write a program that will let the user input a name of software and how many are in stock. I need to store them in an array, then sort it using a selection sort in order from least to greatest amount.

My problem is, I don't want the name of the software separated from the number! Also, IT'S NOT SHOWING THE SORTED NAMES WHEN I COMPILE! I read TONS about selection sorting and they all basically look like this. What could be wrong with it? Did I do the selection sort wrong?

This isn't my whole code, but I don't think I'm leaving out anything crucial:

```
// Global variables
static String[] SoftwareArray;
static int[] QuantityArray;

public static void inputInfo() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader  (new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
    System.out.print("How many softwares would you like to input? ");
    String software = userInput.readLine();
    int softwareNum = Integer.parseInt(software);  
    int[] softArray = new int[softwareNum];      

    String [] name = new String [softwareNum];
    int [] quantity = new int[softwareNum];      

    // Initialize global variables
    SoftwareArray = new String[softwareNum];
    QuantityArray = new int[softwareNum];

    //loop through number of softwares  
    for (int i = 0; i < softwareNum; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input name of software: ");
        String softwareName = userInput.readLine();

        name[i] = softwareName;

        System.out.println("Input quantity of software: ");
        String quantityString = userInput.readLine();
        int softwareQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);  

        quantity[i] = softwareQuantity;

        // Copy the software name and quantity to the global variables
        QuantityArray[i] = quantity[i];
        SoftwareArray[i] = name[i];

        System.out.println("There are " + quantity[i] + " of the " + name[i] + " software.");
    }
}

//method to sort and display info
public static void displayInfo(int[] arr, String[] name)
{      
    //sort by quantity
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j] )
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;

                String tempString = name[j];
                name[j] = name[i];
                name[i] = tempString;
            }
        }
        //output
        for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "  " + name[i]);
        }
    }
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   //input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    inputInfo();

    displayInfo(QuantityArray, SoftwareArray);
}
```

The output:

```
How many softwares would you like to input? 2
Input name of software: 
Microsoft
Input quantity of software: 
1000
There are 1000 of the Microsoft software.
Input name of software: 
Linux
Input quantity of software: 
2983
There are 2983 of the Linux software.
```

Then nothing. It doesn't display the sorted list at all.

Comment: can you post some sample input/output for us?

Answer (score 0):

You have a for loop that iterates over `i` in your for loop that iterates over `i`

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j] )
        {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;

            String tempString = name[j];
            name[j] = name[i];
            name[i] = tempString;
        }
    }
    //output
    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i] + "  " + name[i]);
    }
}
```

I think you might have intended to put that second loop outside the first

I think you might have intended to put that loop to be

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
//output
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i] + "  " + name[i]);
}
```

---

On another note, JB Nized is right.  If you want your name to be more coupled with the quantity, you should make a class

```
public class Software
{
    public int quantity;
    public int string;
}
```

Comment: Without it, my IDE gives me lots of errors and exceptions. Any ideas?

Comment: Like you wrote to JB - that's not the source of the issue that the array is not getting sorted - that's merely a printing issue. The reason that the sort doesn't work is mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line:

```
for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
```

to:

```
for(int j=i; j<arr.length; j++)
```

Complete code:

```
public class SelectionSort {

    public static void displayInfo(int[] arr, String[] name)
    {
        //sort by quantity
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i; j<arr.length; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] > arr[j] )
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;

                    String tempString = name[j];
                    name[j] = name[i];
                    name[i] = tempString;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] QuantityArray = {3,2,4,1,5};
        String[] SoftwareArray = {"3","2","4","1","5"};
        displayInfo(QuantityArray, SoftwareArray);
        for(int i=0; i<QuantityArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(QuantityArray[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<QuantityArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(SoftwareArray[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why specifically do you require selection sort as it guarantees a O(n^2) complexity. Moreover I feel that the outer loop should run to length - 1. Check [here](http://techieme.in/techieme/how-selection-sort-works/) to get it right.

Moreover, at present your code gives the following output:

```
How many softwares would you like to input? 3

Input name of software: windows
Input quantity of software: 3
There are 3 of the windows software.

Input name of software: google
Input quantity of software: 2
There are 2 of the google software.

Input name of software: office
Input quantity of software: 4
There are 4 of the office software.

2  google
3  windows
4  office
```

Do you expect something different, if yes could you please add it in the question. Also, this is not selection sort. This seems more of a bubble sort to me.

**EDIT** Pasting back your code which runs on my machine to produce the above output.
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

```
public class Test {

    // Global variables
    static String[] SoftwareArray;
    static int[] QuantityArray;

    public static void inputInfo() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    System.out.print("How many softwares would you like to input? ");
    String software = userInput.readLine();
    int softwareNum = Integer.parseInt(software);
    int[] softArray = new int[softwareNum];

    String[] name = new String[softwareNum];
    int[] quantity = new int[softwareNum];

    // Initialize global variables
    SoftwareArray = new String[softwareNum];
    QuantityArray = new int[softwareNum];

    // loop through number of softwares
    for (int i = 0; i < softwareNum; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input name of software: ");
        String softwareName = userInput.readLine();

        name[i] = softwareName;

        System.out.println("Input quantity of software: ");
        String quantityString = userInput.readLine();
        int softwareQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);

        quantity[i] = softwareQuantity;

        // Copy the software name and quantity to the global variables
        QuantityArray[i] = quantity[i];
        SoftwareArray[i] = name[i];

        System.out.println("There are " + quantity[i] + " of the "
                + name[i] + " software.");
    }
}

// method to sort and display info
public static void displayInfo(int[] arr, String[] name) {
    // sort by quantity
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;

                String tempString = name[j];
                name[j] = name[i];
                name[i] = tempString;
            }
        }
        // output
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "  " + name[i]);
        }
    }
}

// main
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    inputInfo();
    displayInfo(QuantityArray, SoftwareArray);
}
}
```

Comment: I need to use selection because it's what's required in my assignment. That output isn't what I get in my code, but it's what I want!

Comment: do not forget to change the sorting to selection sorting.

Comment: No, wait, it's not giving it to me in order. Neither the order I wrote it in, or the order from least to greatest...